How to prove theorems about mutual inductive types by using tactics in Coq?
Consider following mutual inductive proposition
Inductive TypeA : Prop :=
  | ConstructorA : TypeB -> TypeA
with TypeB : Prop :=
  | ConstructorB : TypeA -> TypeB. 

Here is proof of ~TypeA in functional style
Fixpoint TypeA_is_empty' (a : TypeA) : False :=
  match a with 
  | ConstructorA b' => TypeB_is_empty' b'
  end
with TypeB_is_empty' (b : TypeB) : False :=
  match b with 
  | ConstructorB a' => TypeA_is_empty' a'
  end.

How to prove ~TypeA in tactic style?
I want to be able to prove them as mutual Theorems if something similar exists in Coq
Theorem TypeA_is_empty : ~ TypeA.
Theorem TypeB_is_empty : ~ TypeB.
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros b.
  inversion b as [a].
  apply (TypeA_is_empty a).
Qed.
Proof.
  unfold not.
  intros a.
  inversion a as [b].
  apply (TypeB_is_empty b).
Qed.

Edit: Found that Coq have such syntax for mutual theorems but it throws  error
Lemma TypeA_is_empty : ~ TypeA 
  with TypeB_is_empty : ~ TypeB.

**Cannot find common (mutual) inductive premises or coinductive conclusions in the statements.**


(I have changed names around for convenience.)
First of all, you cannot use not in the statement, this one compiles:
Lemma A_is_empty : A -> False
  with B_is_empty : B -> False.

That said, this code seems to do it.  See the comments for the explanation:
Inductive A : Prop :=
  | mkA : B -> A
with B : Prop :=
  | mkB : A -> B.

Fixpoint A_is_empty' (a : A) : False :=
  match a with
  | mkA b => B_is_empty' b
  end
with B_is_empty' (b : B) : False :=
  match b with
  | mkB a => A_is_empty' a
  end.

Lemma A_is_empty : A -> False
  with B_is_empty : B -> False.
Proof.
  - intros a.
    apply A_is_empty.
    exact a.
  - intros b.
    apply B_is_empty.
    exact b.
Fail Qed. (* Recursive call to A_is_empty
  has principal argument equal to
  "a" instead of a subterm of "a". *)
Abort.

Lemma A_is_empty : A -> False
  with B_is_empty : B -> False.
Proof.
  - intros a.
    destruct a as [b].  (* !! *)
    apply B_is_empty.
    exact b.
  - intros b.
    destruct b as [a].  (* !! *)
    apply A_is_empty.
    exact a.
Qed.

Check A_is_empty : ~ A.
Check B_is_empty : ~ B.


Thank you, so it means that we need to unfold some definitions(like definition of the not in this case) if we want to prove 'mutual' theorem

Indeed, the parser (I think it is the parser, not yet the type-checker, but I am not sure) does not do any definition unfolding, and a "Lemma with" needs premises/conclusions to match the mutual closes, i.e. something overall of the form A -> B or equivalent.  That is not in fact documented in much detail: here is some discussion on that on the Coq Zulip.

Fixpoint TypeA_is_empty (a:TypeA) : False.
  enough (forall (b:TypeB), False) as TypeB_is_empty.
  destruct a as [b]. apply (TypeB_is_empty b). 
  intros b. destruct b as [a']. apply (TypeA_is_empty a').
Defined.

Use Fixpoint instead of Lemma because you need the TypeA_is_empty inside the proof.
